# How to make a building (view: top down) that looks like a "3d" building with cocos2d and cocos3d? (for iphone)

Tags: iphone, image, 2d, building, cocos3d

In GTA (the first and second game) you can see the city from above.

I think the building are just 5 surfaces and each surface has an image on it. 
If the player moves nearer to the building you will notice this "effect" of a "real building"...

I hope you understood what I mean :S. 
How to build such a building with 5 surfaces in cocos3d. cocos3d uses cocos2d. 
I just want to use cocos3d to build the buildings. The rest will be "2D".

The camera will be moving on the x and y axis.
How could I do that? Any ideas? Sample code would be great but with explanation ;).

Thank you very much.
cocos2dbeginner

Answer (score 4):

There's a very basic project here that shows how to create a very basic 3D World with cubes :

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andyman/bigbot-smash-city/posts/88032

Have a look at the source code and you should get the first steps about how to  use cocos3D programmatically.